# Why does max-height behave differently than max-width on a DIV?

Tags: css

I have simple html as follows:

```
<div style="max-width: 800px; max-height: 300px; background-color: pink;">
    text goes here
</div>
```

The DIV is indeed 800px wide when the page is displayed, but its height remains just enough to hold the text.

I looked at the definitions of max-height and max-width at

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

I cannot seem to find the difference.

Is there any way I can set the height of a DIV to its max height at play display? Or I have to just use the height property?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div's `width` is 100% by default if it has content in it. While `height` takes on only its content's height unless specified differently. See this fiddle for an example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WnXA/1/)